# Find $x<31$ such that $x^{92}$ is congruent to $5 \pmod {31}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find $x<31$ such that $x^{92}$ is congruent to $5 \pmod {31}$.

Should I apply Euler's totient theorem here? I could split  $x^{92}$ into $x^{31}$, $x^{31}$, and $x^{30}$, but $x^{30}$ wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

31 is prime.
If $\gcd (x,31) = 1, x^{30}\equiv 1\pmod{31}$ (Fermat's little theorem)

$x^{92} \equiv x^2\pmod{31}$

Find $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 5\pmod {31}$

$36 \equiv 5\pmod {31}\\
x = \pm6$

or $\{6,25\}$

Comment: There are two solutions.

Comment: oh, indeed $-6$ is also a solution

Answer (score 0):

$$x^{92}=x^{30}x^{30}x^{30}x^2\equiv 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot x^2\pmod{31}$$by Euler's theorem and since $\varphi(31)=30$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^{92}\equiv 5\mod 31$, $x$ is not divisible by $31$, so we can use *lil' Fermat*: $x^{30}\equiv 1\mod 31$, so 
$$x^{92}\equiv x^{92\bmod30}=x^2\mod 31.$$
So it comes down to finding the square roots of $5$ modulo $31$. Let's draw up the list of squares mod.$31$ (different from $0,1$) until we obtain $5$ (or not, but the law of quadratic reciprocity shows we'll find solutions):
$$\begin{matrix}
x&\pm 2 & \pm 3 &\pm 4&\pm 5 &\color{red}{\pm6}  \\
\hline
x^2&4&9&-15&-6&\mathbf 5
\end{matrix}$$